# Knowing when a fragment is left from / returned to

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-lifecycle

Android's Fragment's onResume/onPause methods are tightly coupled with the host Activity's lifecycle as shown [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Lifecycle).

What I want to know is how to detect that a fragment is left from / returned to **inside the app's navigation flow.**

*Example:*

Say I have MainActivity and fragments A,B and C.

MainActivity **adds** fragment A, then B and then C.

How do I know fragment B was left (I now see fragment C).

Also, once I press on back, how do I know fragment B was resumed?

**Edit:**

Clarification: I want to know that from within fragment B (similar to the way an Activity works with onPause and onResume)

Comment: I think you should make it clear where do you want to know that? In the host Activity or in the fragment itself?

Comment: When you say adds fragments A, then B, then C you mean in the same container ? Like add A, replace it with B and then replace it with C ?

Comment: yes, all fragments are added to the same container

Answer (score 0):

Try `isDetached()` method [link here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#isDetached())

Respectively there is `isAdded()`

Comment: thanks for your answer. use isDetached() / usAdded() from where? those are final methods I can't override.

Comment: Where you want to make the check?

Comment: Just edited the question. I want to know from fragment B

Answer (score 0):

1. Indirectly you question concern with [Fragment LifeCycle](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Creating).
2. And you can trace fragment navigation replace,remove,add using [Fragment manager](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Managing)
3. [PopBackStack](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager.html#popBackStack()) : Pop the last fragment transition from the manager's fragment back stack. If there is nothing to pop, false is returned.